# Import Birthday's contacts from Gmail into a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using a custom version of the "Contact Listings.gs" script provided by GoogleAppsScript@google.com to import data from Gmail contacts into a Google Spreadsheet.
I fail to import Birthdays.

Here is the code I try to use :

```
function listContacts() {
  var parameters = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValues()[0];
  var group = parameters.shift();

  var people;
  if ((group) && (group!=""))  {
    var contactGroup = ContactsApp.findContactGroup(group);
    if (contactGroup)
      people = contactGroup.getContacts();
  } else
    people = ContactsApp.getAllContacts();

  if (!people)
    return;

  // grab all the contacts
  var retvalues = new Array();
  for (var i in people) {    
    var value = new Array();
    value.push(people[i].getFullName());
    value.push(people[i].getHomeAddress());
    value.push(people[i].getPrimaryEmail());
    value.push(people[i].getMobilePhone());
    value.push(people[i].getHomePhone());
    value.push(people[i].getDates(ContactsApp.Field.BIRTHDAY));

    for (var j in parameters) {
      var info = people[i]["get"+parameters[j]]();
      value.push(info);
    }
    retvalues.push(value);
  }

  var r;
  if ((group) || (parameters.length>0))
    r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRowIndex()+1;
  else
    r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();

  var c = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getColumnIndex();
  if (retvalues.length>0)
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(r,c,retvalues.length,retvalues[0].length).setValues(retvalues);
  else
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(r,c).setValue("No contacts found.");
}
```

The script fills the cell with "DateField" instead of a readable birthday date.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `getDates()` method returns an array of objects, each of them have [specific methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contact#getDates()) to retrieve days or month.

In you code replace the line

```
value.push(people[i].getDates(ContactsApp.Field.BIRTHDAY));
```

with this code

```
var dates = [];
var birthdays = people[i].getDates(ContactsApp.Field.BIRTHDAY);
for (var i in birthdays) {
  dates.push(birthdays[i].getMonth()+'/'+birthdays[i].getDay());
}
value.push(dates.join(' + '));// in case there is more than 1 birthday  !?!
```

### EDIT :

*following comment*

To show values in numeric date format, add this line at the end of the code :

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,6,retvalues.length,1).setNumberFormat('d/MM/yyyy');
```

Comment: Excellent ! Thank you very much.
But is there a way to return month into a numeric instead of letters ?

Comment: Your spreadsheet can do that, just play with the column format ... I used a / separator to force he value to become a date in spreadsheet if desired.

Comment: or using script, simply add     `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,6,retvalues.length,1).setNumberFormat('d/MM/yyyy');` at the end of the script

Comment: No offense, I thought I could accept more than an only answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had never played with dates in the `ContactApp` before and I have to say, it is horrible. What crazy `DateField` object. Here's my solution:

```js
function listContacts() {
  var contactGroup = ContactsApp.findContactGroup('System Group: Family');
  if( !contactGroup ) throw 'Group not found';
  var people = contactGroup.getContacts();

  var values = [['FullName','Address','Email','Mobile','Phone','Birthday']];
  for( var i in people ) {    
    var birthday = people[i].getDates(ContactsApp.Field.BIRTHDAY);
    values.push([
      people[i].getFullName(),
      people[i].getHomeAddress(),
      people[i].getPrimaryEmail(),
      people[i].getMobilePhone(),
      people[i].getHomePhone(),
      birthday.length ? parseDateField(birthday[0]) : '',
    ]);
  }

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  s.getDataRange().clear();
  s.getRange(1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
}

function parseDateField(df) {
  return new Date(
    df.getYear(),
    {JANUARY:0,FEBRUARY:1,MARCH:2,APRIL:3,MAY:4,JUNE:5,JULY:6,
     AUGUST:7,SEPTEMBER:8,OCTOBER:9,NOVEMBER:10,DECEMBER:11}[df.getMonth()],
    df.getDay());
}
```

The difference of this solution instead of using a "/" separator and let the spreadsheet parse it: is that this doesn't rely on the spreadsheet, which may be important if you want to use this date directly in your code, e.g. the `CalendarApp`

Comment: Thanks Henrique :-)  With the last update I added in the code the values will be dates in spreadsheet for sure but it's true that your solution allows fir **direct use** of dates as JS dates... thanks, upvoted !

Comment: @Sergeinsas Yours is a nice solution too, I only saw it after I posted (nearly half an hour later!). But by the way, this DateField object is unnecessarily stupid. I'm truly impressed!

Comment: You're right... I guess the idea was that a birthday should not have a "year" property (and no time value either) because of its recurrent nature... but that's pretty silly, I agree.